# How to determine that ARObjectAnchor was removed from the scene?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, ios13

I am trying to use ARKit for validating the position of a toy. I have an ARObject scan resource, and placing the toy in camera view works pretty well. In other words, `didAdd` and `didUpdate` of `SCNScene` and `ARSession` are called as expected in a reasonable time after the toy is placed in camera view. But when i move the toy away from the camera view, `didRemove` does **not** get called, neither for `SCNScene` nor for `ARSession`.

I did read advocations of this behaviour, saying "well ARKit can't know if it was really removed and it still may be just around the corner" but it is rather impractical assumption. The whole Apple documentation about this function is "ARKit may automatically remove anchors" but doesn't say a word about when and why. I know about [isTracked](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable/2928210-istracked) but `ARObjectAnchor` seems to be *the only ARAnchor subclass that does not implement ARTrackable*.

The only desperate hack i can think of is some kind of fuzzy timeout for when `didUpdate` stops getting called, because that's the only effect of removing the object AFAIK. Did i overlook something in `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpretation of informations from Apple TSI (id 731233593 if anyone wants to refer to this issue in his own TSI):

**ARObjectAnchors are not necessarily removed when the object goes offscreen. It is not a behaviour that should be relied on.** This applies to `AR(SCNView|Session)Delegate.didRemove` callbacks and to the content of `ARFrame.anchors`. The callbacks are definitely called only if the client code removes the relevant anchor programmatically. I was unable to squeeze a better explanation of the official doc line "ARKit may automatically remove anchors" despite asking explicitly. "*You shouldn’t worry about why this happened.*"

**Timing out on `didAdd` or `didUpdate` callbacks is an official method.** The evidence is [Apple's official project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) for creating object scans, file `Controllers/TestRun.swift` method `startNoDetectionTimer`. Using 5 seconds timeout.

Demands of `ARObjectAnchor` to implement `ARTrackable` are encouraged to fill an enhancement request at [Feedback Assistant](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). I personally was encouraged to investigate alternatives and found that CoreML is unexpectedly friendly and fits my use case much better.

Thanks @Andy for pushing me this far.

Answer (score 1):

To find an anchor by name give it a descriptive name using **`init(name:transform:)`** initialiser:

```
let anchor = ARAnchor.init(name: "ObjAnchor", transform: mtx) as! ARObjectAnchor

self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.anchors.filter { 
     $0.name == "ObjAnchor"
}
```

or:

```
self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.anchors.contains { 
    $0.isKind(of: ARObjectAnchor.self)
}
```

> 

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i was misunderstood apparently. I have clarified the first chapter. The problem is not in finding the anchor. ARKit gives it the same name as the arboject scan resource, and that's good enough. The problem is when the object is physically removed from the camera view. ARKit does not give any infornation about such event, other than stopping issuing didUpdate for that anchor.

Comment: Unfortunately `ARFrame.anchors` doesn't work either :( Despite being a property of the frame, the Apple doc says "_list of anchors representing objects detected **in the scene**_" and that's really how it behaves. Once the anchor object is recognized, it hangs in the array forever, despite being moved out of the camera sight. We annotated the ARAnchor's node with a floating label, and the label stays where the object was last recognized.

Comment: Interestingly, if the anchor object is moved but still stays in the camera view, the relevant object node moves too, though after quite disappointingly long time. But when it's yanked away completely, the object node just sits at the last known place forever. Along the anchor in `ARFrame.anchors`. I think i'm gonna burn an Apple TSI on this.

Comment: You're right. I'm working on corrected version of my answer.